# Ayuda con ejercicio php de funciones

Tags: php, array, funciones

Ayuda no logro decifrar donde me estoy equivocando.

Escribir la función dobles que reciba un argumento. Este argumento será un array de números y es tu trabajo retornar un nuevo array con el doble de cada uno de los números recibidos.

```
 function dobles($numero) {
           $numero = array();
            for ($i=1; $i < count($numero); $i++) { 
           $nuevoArray[] = $i * 2;
            }
return $nuevoArray = [];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le estas asignando un arreglo vació a tu arreglo que viene por parámetro

Estas multiplicando el $i por 2, en vez de multiplicar el numero en la posicion $i por 2

Ademas estas retornando $nuevoArray = []; lo que significa que estas retornando un arreglo vació

Prueba con este codigo

```
function dobles($numero) {
    $nuevoArray = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < count($numero); $i++) { 
        $nuevoArray[] = $numero[$i] * 2;
    }
    return $nuevoArray;
}
```